# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-core:jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to download maven dependencies to my netbeans build maven web application. ince I couldn't update dependencies through IDE I tried to do it using

```
mvn clean install
```

Command trough cmd. 

But I still got the same error. 
[image]

Please help. I'm trying to figure this out for days. (Internet connection is working pretty fine.) 
THank you

**EDIT**

This is the output.

```
C:\Users\Dilini\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewSpring>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building NewSpring 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RC3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RC3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.RC3 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.552 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-24T15:24:58+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project NewSpring: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.dilini:NewSpring:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RC3, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RC3, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.RC3: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RC3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

C:\Users\Dilini\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewSpring>
```

Comment: The message is telling you that the missing JARs are not available in the repository you're pointing to.  I'd recommend going to that repo and confirming it.  It might be that the version you're asking for isn't correct.

Comment: Add the output as text not as an image

Comment: Why you want to use a RC not a released spring version

Comment: @Jens what is a RC?

Comment: A **R**elease **C**andidate

Comment: The last released Version is `4.3.10.RELEASE`

Comment: @Jens can you please suggest best dependency from this link for springframework https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring

Comment: I would use `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Thank you. You are a savior.. @Jens after I changed those versions to released versions everything has built successfully. Thank you so much..

Comment: @pippilongstocking You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this repo to your pom file:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Can I know what is that. So should I keep other dependencies

Comment: Since the version of spring-core you are using is not released yet i.e. it is a Candidate Release (RC  `5.0.0.RC3`) they are stored in Spring repository.